# Kubernetes pod FileLockException: Lock file has been locked by another process - neo4j 4.2

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, neo4j

As per part of our Kubernetes deployment of neo4j 4.2, we are getting this exception. We got only 1 pod running and now its going into CrashloopBackoff. The backend is Google filestore, but as of now no one is accessing that. Need help -

```
2021-09-16 17:43:00.981+0000 INFO  Starting...
2021-09-16 17:43:02.873+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 4.2.9 ========
2021-09-16 17:43:08.511+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j on dbms.connector.http.listen_address, a socket address. If missing port or hostname it is acquired from dbms.default_listen_address.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting Neo4j database server at /data/databases
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:207) ~[neo4j-4.2.9.jar:4.2.9]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.build(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:163) ~[neo4j-4.2.9.jar:4.2.9]
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.createNeo(CommunityBootstrapper.java:36) ~[neo4j-4.2.9.jar:4.2.9]
        at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:134) [neo4j-4.2.9.jar:4.2.9]
        at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:90) [neo4j-4.2.9.jar:4.2.9]
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:35) [neo4j-4.2.9.jar:4.2.9]
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.internal.locker.LockerLifecycleAdapter@a8a8b75' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Lock file has been locked by another process: /data/databases/store_lock. Please ensure no other process is using this database, and that the directory is writable (required even for read-only access)".
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:463) ~[neo4j-common-4.2.9.jar:4.2.9]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:110) ~[neo4j-common-4.2.9.jar:4.2.9]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:198) ~[neo4j-4.2.9.jar:4.2.9]
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.internal.locker.FileLockException: Lock file has been locked by another process: /data/databases/store_lock. Please ensure no other process is using this database, and that the directory is writable (required even for read-only access)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.internal.locker.Locker.storeLockException(Locker.java:175) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.9.jar:4.2.9]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.internal.locker.Locker.checkLock(Locker.java:95) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.9.jar:4.2.9]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.internal.locker.GlobalFileLocker.checkLock(GlobalFileLocker.java:58) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.9.jar:4.2.9]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.internal.locker.GlobalLocker.checkLock(GlobalLocker.java:28) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.9.jar:4.2.9]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.internal.locker.LockerLifecycleAdapter.start(LockerLifecycleAdapter.java:36) ~[neo4j-kernel-4.2.9.jar:4.2.9]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:442) ~[neo4j-common-4.2.9.jar:4.2.9]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:110) ~[neo4j-common-4.2.9.jar:4.2.9]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:198) ~[neo4j-4.2.9.jar:4.2.9]
        ... 5 more
2021-09-16 17:43:08.515+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
2021-09-16 17:43:08.515+0000 INFO  Stopped.
```

Comment: Maybe include an init container to your deployment, to make sure that folder is writable and also to rm the lock in case if exist

Comment: What should I do to delete the lock?

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?  (Are you trying to mount the same PersistentVolumeClaim into multiple Pods; maybe as part of a Deployment rather than a StatefulSet?)

Comment: @Hackerman I do already have init container and the whole data directory is writeable. I have the same setup running in other two environments and this environment was running since last 10 days, but suddenly this error has started coming.

Comment: @Hackerman I got 2 init containers. First one ensures that data directory exist (if not it will create it) with correct permissions. Second one ensure that neo4j admin is called to take backup of the data directory. After that main container starts.

Also, we restart the kubernetes deployment daily to trigger the 2nd init container for backup. As of now, even the 2nd init container is also giving error saying that it cannot complete backup because neo4j is already in use.

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't have a reproducible example. The same setup is running for over a month now in other environment. As I mentioned above, we got 2 init containers. We mount the same PVC across the 2 init containers and then to main neo4j container. Once 1st one ensures that directory is there with required permissions and 2nd one ensures that backup is complete, 3rd containers then uses the same PVC to start neo4j

Comment: @Hackerman Can you also advise which file can I delete to resolve this issue meanwhile?

Comment: @Hackerman Here is the permission on the data directory --> drwxr-xr-x    5 7474     7474          4096 Aug 27 18:22 data

Answer (score 2):

Using google filestore in lieu of regular persistent volume claims is not recommended; for performance reasons Neo4j needs high speed, performant local disks, typically they recommend SSDs.  Using a filestore like cloud abstraction, if it works, is likely to result in degraded performance.

Now in general, the error you're seeing refers to files on disk being locked by a different process.  This can happen because a previous (crashed) version of Neo4j locked it, or it could be due to volume issues, here is where you'd have to research deep into how filestore provides a POSIX complaint drive on something like GKE.

Comment: Thanks for replying, yes we found the issue wherein previous crashed version locked it.